# Keep Parent Menu Option Active Class & Apply Active Class To Child Menu Option When Selected

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have a side menu on my `asp.net` website and when i click the left hand menu i have some JQuery which adds the `class="active"` for me and keeps it until the user navigates away from the page (this works fine) but now i need to add 2 sub menu's to one of the optnion's but i want the top level to retain the `class="active"` and also apply the `class="active"` to the selected menu but i dont know how to do this

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //HIGHLIGHTS SELECTED MENU OPTION IN MAIN MENU AND LEFT HAND MENU
          var url = window.location;
          $('ul.nav a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

          // MAIN MENU
          $('ul.navbar-nav a').filter(function () {
               return this.href == url;
          }).parent().addClass('active');

          // LEFT HAND MENU MENU
          $('ul.nav-stacked a').filter(function () {
               return this.href == url;
          }).parent().addClass('active');
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked">
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About us</a></li>
          <ul class="nav nav-stackedsub">
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/testpage1">test1</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/testpage2">test2</a></li>
          </ul>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-stacked > li > a {
  color: #999999;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: ITCLubalinGraphStdBook;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #999999;
}

.nav-stacked > li > a:hover,
.nav-stacked > li > a:focus {
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-stacked > .active > a,
.nav-stacked > .active > a:hover,
.nav-stacked > .active > a:focus {
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-stackedsub > li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.nav-stackedsub > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-stackedsub > li > a {
  color: #999999;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: ITCLubalinGraphStdBook;
  color: #575b5f;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #999999;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your script:

```
// SUB MENU
$('ul.nav-stackedsub a').filter(function () {
   return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
// apply active class to the li before the ul class of the submenu
$('ul.nav-stackedsub a').filter(function () {
   return this.href == url;
}).parent().parent().prev('li').addClass('active');
```

And this to your css:

```
.nav-stackedsub > .active > a,
.nav-stackedsub > .active > a:hover,
.nav-stackedsub > .active > a:focus{
  color: lightblue;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

And I think that should do what you're looking for!

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Great, glad I could help!